# Is NetworkManager sending HTTP requests to googleusercontent.com?

Tags: networking, network-manager, lsof

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 on my desktop PC, I've been monitoring network traffic with Etherape. I noticed HTTP requests from my PC(casa hostname) to googleusercontent.com (104.198.143.177).
So I used `lsof` and `ss` to 'identify' process behind these requests.

Using `lsof -i`:

```
NetworkMa  778            root   20u  IPv4 546772      0t0  TCP casa:53671->177.143.198.104.bc.googleusercontent.com:http (SYN_SENT)
NetworkMa  778            root   20u  IPv4 546772      0t0  TCP casa:53671->177.143.198.104.bc.googleusercontent.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
```

Using `ss -rep dst 104.198.143.177`:

```
tcp    SYN-SENT   0      1      casa%enp4s0:53671    177.143.198.104.bc.googleusercontent.com:http  users:(("NetworkManager",pid=778,fd=20)) timer:(on,964ms,0) ino:546772 sk:6df <->
tcp    ESTAB      0      87     casa%enp4s0:53671    177.143.198.104.bc.googleusercontent.com:http  users:(("NetworkManager",pid=778,fd=20)) timer:(on,300ms,0) ino:546772 sk:6df <->
```

It seems NetworkManager (pid 778) is sending requests to googleusercontent, and it happens **every 5 minutes** exactly.

I have to say, no applications were launched at the moment, no background process, no network activities,no online account and it was a 'Ubuntu fresh install'.
So why NM would sent requests to googleusercontent?

Comment: It's a feature coming with Ubuntu 17.10.NetworkManager pings regularly http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com (bc.googleusercontent.com).In order to check connectivity.Disable in settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to take into account the 1st bit of that:

```
bc.googleusercontent.com
```

bc originates from Google Compute Engine (Google cloud) That does not have to be from Google itself. It is a service anyone can use.

177.143.198.104 is owned by NET Serviços de Comunicação S.A. Is that your ISP perhaps?

---

Some other services that are from Google:

- **lh3.googleusercontent.com** Used for loading images for Google+.
- **lh5.googleusercontent.com** Used for loading images for Google+.
- **lh6.googleusercontent.com** Used for loading images for Google+.
- **s3.googleusercontent.com** Used for loading favicons for AdWords ads.
- **static.googleusercontent.com**
- **themes.googleusercontent.com** Used for loading font files for Google Fonts. (Generally called within CSS from fonts.googleapis.com)
- **translate.googleusercontent.com** Google Translation Service

Answer (score 2):

Looking up the IP, I found [this](https://ipinfo.io/104.198.143.177):

```
Hosted Domains  connectivity-check.ubuntu.com
                177.143.198.104.bc.googleusercontent.com
```

So it's an Ubuntu page hosted by Google.